# float:right doesn't work even though the anchor element is within a div

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to make a sidebar, which has an 'X' button at the top right corner. I tried to use `float: right` in order to place it on the right but it doesn't work.

The anchor that I used for the cross is within a div, but I don't know why it doesn't seem to work. I don't think the css with .side-nav .btn-close contains the problem.

I think there's something wrong with the side-nav class.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border;
}

html {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    color:white;
}

.navbar-links ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    left: 1rem;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: none;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
}

.side-nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #9ed39f;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: flex;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
    font-size: 36px;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    float:right;
    margin-right:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Responsive Sidebar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="logo">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="navbar-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Abvout</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="side-nav">
      <a href="#" class="btn-close">&times;</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <main>
     epturi, quod illo. Voluptatum
      alias possimus ipsum omnis. Aspernatur animi debitis natus sed
      exercitationem repudiandae excepturi, ipsum hi
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using floats anyway. They're an obsolete means of aligning things that has few modern uses.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use anchors as buttons. Use buttons.

Comment: Your example works for me. Did you notice that the color of the link is white ? Maybe that's why you don't see it ?

Comment: @ethanfar it works well this way, but when I run all of my code, it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe there's something wrong with the other codes i am messing around with.

Comment: @성균관대안유진 You're probably right, it must be something else with the code. Either share more code, or just a working example as a snippet (jsfiddle, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply because `float` doesn't work on `flex` items. Your `.side-nav` has the display of `flex`. If you change it to `block`, it will work.

But my suggestion is not to use float at all. Because float is mainly for old newspaper-like text-image combination and using it to "structure the elements" was just a hack because of the lack of the flex-box.

So either stick with one of them (float or flex-box) Or better: make the close icon an absolutely positioned element to get it out of the flow:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    color:white;
}

.navbar-links ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    left: 1rem;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: none;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
}

.side-nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #9ed39f;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: flex;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
    font-size: 36px;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right:25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Responsive Sidebar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="logo">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="navbar-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Abvout</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="side-nav">
      <a href="#" class="btn-close">&times;</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <main>
     epturi, quod illo. Voluptatum
      alias possimus ipsum omnis. Aspernatur animi debitis natus sed
      exercitationem repudiandae excepturi, ipsum hi
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

ALSO: Notice that `box-sizing: border-box;` is correct, not `box-sizing: border;`

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a little. It should work now.

I have added wrapper `div` to your `button` and the `ul` in sidebar. Since you are using `position:fixed` on `.side-nav`, you have to use `position: absolute` on the `X Button`.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border;
    }

    html {
      background-color: #dfdfdf;
    }

    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    .logo {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      margin: .5rem;
      color: white;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar-links li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      display: block;
      padding: 1rem;
    }

    .toggle-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: .75rem;
      left: 1rem;
      width: 30px;
      height: 21px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      display: none;
    }

    .toggle-button .bar {
      background-color: white;
      width: 100%;
      height: 3px;
    }

    .side-nav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 250px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #9ed39f;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      display: flex;
    }

    .side-nav .btn-close {
      font-size: 36px;
      border-bottom: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 25px;
    }

/* Added These 2 Wrapper class */
    .btn-close-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .ul-wrapper {
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Responsive Sidebar</title>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="logo">Brand Name</div>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Abvout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="side-nav">
  
    <!-- Used wrapper div for close button and ul -->
    <div class="btn-close-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="btn-close">&times;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ul-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
    epturi, quod illo. Voluptatum
    alias possimus ipsum omnis. Aspernatur animi debitis natus sed
    exercitationem repudiandae excepturi, ipsum hi
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```